# gmaps4rails gem: to_gmaps4rails method undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps-api-3, gmaps4rails

I'm trying to dynamically update the markers on a google map using gmaps4rails (i.e. with an AJAX call back). I'm finding the documentation for gmaps4rails very scattered and unclear.

I've successfully been able to display markers on a map using the build_markers method (as per the video tutorial v2).

My controller code:

```
# GET /telemetry_recordings
def index

    @telemetry_recordings = TelemetryRecording.all
    @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@telemetry_recordings) do |telemetry_recording, marker|
            marker.lat telemetry_recording.latitude
            marker.lng telemetry_recording.longitude
            marker.title telemetry_recording.delivery_unit.driver.full_name
            marker.infowindow telemetry_recording.delivery_unit.driver.full_name
    end
end
```

My view code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
    handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
        markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
        handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
        handler.fitMapToBounds();
    });
</script>
```

Now, to implement a dynamic update, I've added the following script to my view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
        $('body').on('click', '#replace_markers', function(){ 
            $.getJSON("/telemetry_recordings", function(data){
                Gmaps.map.replaceMarkers(data);
            });
        });
    });   
</script>
```

As well as a button:

```
<button id="replace_markers">Refresh</button>
```

And, I've added the following code to my controller:

```
respond_to :json, :html

# GET /telemetry_recordings
def index

    @json = TelemetryRecording.all.to_gmaps4rails
    respond_with @json

end
```

Note: TelemetryRecording class has 3 attributes: latitude (float), longitude (float) and location_time (DateTime)

This results in the following error:

```
undefined method `to_gmaps4rails' for #<TelemetryRecording::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x55dee78>
```

As per the documentation, I've installed the gmaps4rails gem, added *//= require underscore* and
*//= require gmaps/google* to my application.js file, and included the following scripts in my view:

```
<script src="//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.14/src/markerclusterer_packed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.13&sensor=false&libraries=geometry" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Am I using to_gmaps4rails correctly here? (my understanding is that it converts an object with latitude/longitude attributes to an array of markers, e.g. [{"lat":"x", "lng":"y"}, {"lat":"x", "lng":"y"}]. Why is it undefined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using code from v1.x and 2.x.

`to_gmaps4rails` has been removed from the code base. So your first shot was ok:

```
def index
  @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(TelemetryRecording.all) do |telemetry_recording, marker|
     marker.lat telemetry_recording.latitude
     marker.lng telemetry_recording.longitude
     marker.title telemetry_recording.delivery_unit.driver.full_name
     marker.infowindow telemetry_recording.delivery_unit.driver.full_name
  end
  respond_with @hash
end
```

and in the js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
    handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
        var markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
        handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
        handler.fitMapToBounds();

        $('body').on('click', '#replace_markers', function(){ 
            $.getJSON("/telemetry_recordings", function(newMarkers){
                handler.removeMarkers(markers); // to remove previous markers
                markers = handler.addMarkers(newMarkers);
            });
        });
    });   
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Ah that makes so much sense.... sorry I was really confused with the versions. Now works beautifully. thanks so much. (including for the great gem). One further question, does the gem include an option to dynamically update the map when underlying location data changes in the model? If so, any chance you have a resource/example/explainer that could help us folks out here? thanks!

Comment: its just a wrapper to get markers displayed with human methods. No extra logic as auto update etc

Comment: sorry i didn't understand a word of that